# Sorting GPS Coordinates in SQL

Tags: sql-server, gps

Please forgive me if this is posted somewhere. Believe me I've looked but not quite finding specifically what I'm looking for. I'm trying to create a Ranked Sequence using a database of GPS Coordinates. It has to cycle through beginning with a provided starting location THEN find the next closest GPS location. Using straight distance calculations won't do the trick and neither will the TSP logic because i need to calculate from each point (house level).

I'm using a function to calculate distance from a starting location but that doesn't solve my problem.

Example.
Provided starting warehouse coordinate =  38.737012,    -90.748255
Next closest coordinate (Point A) =  38.737012, -90.615291
This is where I'm stuck. I now need to cycle through the entire database to find the closest point to Point A.
Then repeat until all is done.
Point A to Point B.
Point B to Point C

```sql
Declare @StartingWarehouseLatitude as decimal(9,6) = 38.807544
Declare @StartingWarehouseLongitude as decimal(9,6) = -90.748255

Select
 [COUNTY],
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by [Op Center] ORDER BY [Op Center] desc,CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Latitude,128),', ',CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Longitude,128))) AS RouteSequence,
 Latitude,
 Longitude,
 [dbo].[fnCalcDistanceMiles](@StartingWarehouseLatitude,@StartingWarehouseLongitude,Latitude,Longitude) as DistanceinMile

 from GPSData  ----

ORDER BY [Op Center] desc,CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Latitude,128),', ',CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Longitude,128))
```

Comment: Have you tried using the geography type? SQL Server actually has some built in functions to calculate distance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stdistance-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using the geography data type in SQL Server:

```sql
declare @locations table (Id int, position geography)

insert into @locations values 
    (1, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(50 50)', 4326)),
    (2, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(50 70)', 4326)),
    (3, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(50 80)', 4326))

declare @location geography = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(50 71)', 4326)

select Id, position.STAsText() from @locations l order by @location.STDistance(l.position)
```

Comment: If the points are in an actual table, you can add a spatial index to the geography column which is designed to aid in this type of query.